# Gifsicle on CentOS? x86_64

Tags: linux, x86, debian, centos

I am trying to install Gifsicle on my server which is CentOS x86_64. I do not know which package to use or how to install it. Can someone with experience help me out?

http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/

Comment: Which version of CentOS, please? Also, you can often reuse old rpm packaging. You'll need a source rpm, and then you can use the old spec file with minor modifications with the new sources.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to download the source and compile it yourself, you should try to locate  a RPM for your platform (e.g. from http://packages.sw.be/gifsicle/),
and install it using

```
rpm -Uvh <filename>
```

Comment: I have no idea how to compile. It looks like those rpm's are old versions. The latest version is 1.61 I believe. Are their any alternatives for gif resizing? Imagemagick is slow and does not handle animations well

Comment: Compiling should be pretty straightforward - download the source, extract it, change to the directory and run ./configure && make && sudo make install

Answer (score 0):

I am way late to the party, but! An RPM for gifsicle 1.68 is available on repoforge [edit: link removed because StackOverflow privileges]. I was able to install this on CentOS 6.7.

Fedora maintains [RPMs for the latest versions of gifsicle](http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=gifsicle), but they don't appear to work for me on CentOS 6.7. The gifsicle 1.88 package requires GLIBC 2.14, and CentOS 6.7 (which I'm using) is stuck on 2.12. Folks on CentOS 7 might have better luck installing the package, though.

[Edit] EPEL now has a gifsicle 1.88 package for RHEL/Centos 6: https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/repoview/gifsicle.html